# Ruby, mysql connection failure

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to connect to a mysql db with a ruby script. The code looks like

```
def self.connect_to_db()
  db_params = self.get_db_connection_params() 
  begin
    connection = ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(db_params)
    puts "Successfully connected to DB"
    self.verify_connection(connection)
  rescue Exception => e
    puts "Error while connecting to DB: #{e}"
  end
end



def self.verify_connection(connection)
begin
  puts "Verifying connection.."
  q = "select * from users;"
  @result = connection.connection.execute(q)
  @result.each(:as => :hash) do |row| 
     puts row["name"] 
  end
  puts "Verified"
rescue Exception => e
  puts "Error while verifying: #{e}"
end
```

end

but iam getting exception:
Error while verifying:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago.
The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

The database exists on a different host.
I am able to connect to the db using mysql client through command line.

Comment: Can you post your `database.yml` file code?

Comment: Got it fixed. I was using incorrect port number for db params.